# How to print values from an array in a calendar format?

Tags: java, arrays, string-formatting

So I have two months array that store events time,date and priority called:

```
Events[] september= new Events[30];
Events[] october = new Events[31];
```

I want to insert my days array in them and make them appear in a particular format.

```
 static String[] days = {"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20","21","22","23","24","25","26","27","28","29","30"};
```

How do I get an output like this? I can't seem to find my way around:

```
Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat
     1   2*  3   4   5   6
 7   8   9  10  11* 12* 13
14* 15* 16* 17  18  19* 20
21  22  23  24  25* 26* 27
28* 29  30
```

I wrote two different codes for it My code is:

```
public static void DisplayEvents(Events[] event,int firstWeekday) {
    System.out.println("Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat");
    for(int i =0; i<days.length;i++) {
        System.out.println(String.format("%1$5s", days[i]) +"");

    }
```

and

```
public static void DisplayEvents(Events[] event,int firstWeekday) {
    int weekDayIndex =0;

    System.out.println("Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat");
    for(int day=1; day<days.length; day++){
        System.out.println(" ");
        weekDayIndex++;
    }
    for(int day =1; day<event.length;day++){
        System.out.print(String.format("%1$5s", day));
        weekDayIndex++;
        if (weekDayIndex== 7){
            weekDayIndex = 0;
            System.out.println();
        } else {
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }

}
```

The output theses codes give me instead is :

Updated Output:

```
Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat
1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26   27   28   29   30
```

The asterisks signifies days that have events being held. I already wrote a code to put in random events and I have my asterisks. My problem is just printing it in the calendar format and being able to place my asterisks on the days that have events. Any contribution/help would be appreciated. I can provide more info if its needed.

Comment: @MadProgrammer: The OP is already using String.format, so I think you'll need to be a bit more precise...

Comment: @JonSkeet Missed that, thanks

Comment: So, you've got two pieces of code - how close do they come? What does their output look like? Note that there's no useful difference between `System.out.println()` and `System.out.println("")` so you might want to look at that if/else statement again.

Comment: I updated the output gives me instead of the required one. @JonSkeet

Comment: Right - so have you debugged through the code to work out *why* you're getting that output? You've clearly got too many new lines, so the first thing to do is look at each `println` call and work out whether it should *really* be creating a new line.

Comment: What do you think something like `System.out.println(String.format("%1$5s", day));` in your `for(int day =1; day<event.length;day++){` loop is doing for you?

Comment: Event[] september = new String[30]; is not valid.

Comment: So, I removed some unnecessary new lines and got the output on an horizontal line.The only problem now is how to get it to stop at 6 on Sat and create a new line @JonSkeet

Comment: forgot to remove that while editing, fixed. @matt

Comment: Right, so now you want *a* call to `println()`, but only when you've just printed the Saturday... I would definitely concentrate on printing the calendar *without* event markers before you try to add the event markers. That part should be relatively easy.

Comment: Is weekDayIndex larger than 7 when you start.

Comment: I don't understand. The saturday string is also being printed in the **System.out.println("Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat");** Are you suggesting tracking the positions. How is that possible? @JonSkeet

Comment: weekDayIndex is on 0 when it starts @matt

Comment: Right, at the top it is zero. You go through the first loop ( print 4 spaces not 1 btw) so check it's value after that loop. If it is greater than or equal to 7, your next loop will not increment. Since days appears to be length 30, I guess it will be 30.

Comment: can you pin point your suggestion/correction using my code @matt

Comment: One more hint: `for(int day=1; day<days.length; day++)` should actually be `for(int day=0; day<firstWeekDay; day++)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You print out the headers ok. Next step print out the blank spaces.

```
int currentWeekDay = 0;
for(int i = 0; i<firstWeekDay; i++){
    System.out.print("    ");
    currentWeekDay++;
    //just in case the firstWeekDay is invalid.
    if(currentWeekDay==7){
        currentWeekDay=0;
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Now print out the numbers and add a hard return each time.

```
for(int i = 0; i<event.length; i++){
    System.out.printf("%4s", event[i]);
    currentWeekDay++;
    if(currentWeekDay==7){
        currentWeekDay=0;
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Note that I am using the days array of strings you created instead of formatting the index you are iterating over.

Comment: can you explain why you used event.day.length ? My first time seeing .length arr ind like that

Comment: Sorry, that is my mistake. I forgot that event is just an array, I was thinking it is a different object. Ill fix it now. @girlCoder

Answer (score 0):

In this line

```
System.out.println(String.format("%1$5s", day));
```

use `print()` instead of `println()`.

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually, you want to build each row as a single `String` or output, filling all the columns before you print a new line.

The "main" cause is the use of `System.out.println(String.format("%1$5s", day));` in your `for(int day =1; day<event.length;day++){` loop, which is printing out each day on a new line.

Now, there are a number of ways you might be able to achieve this, for example, you could use `System.out.print` instead of `System.out.println` or you could use a predefined format for all 7 days (`"%2s%1s %2s%1s %2s%1s %2s%1s %2s%1s %2s%1s %2s%1s"`) and fill it out

Or you could use something like `StringBuilder` which could represent a single row, generating the output for a given day and appending it to the `StringBuilder`, for example...

```
LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(2015, Month.OCTOBER, 1);
int month = date.getMonthValue();
LocalDate endOfMonth = date.withDayOfMonth(date.lengthOfMonth()).plusDays(1);
while (date.getDayOfWeek() != DayOfWeek.SUNDAY) {
    date = date.minusDays(1);
}

String format = "%2s%1s ";
System.out.println("Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat");
while (date.isBefore(endOfMonth)) {

    StringBuilder row = new StringBuilder(7 * 4);
    for (int index = 0; index < 7; index++) {
        if (month == date.getMonthValue()) {
            row.append(String.format(format, Integer.toString(date.getDayOfMonth()), ""));
        } else {
            row.append(String.format(format, "", ""));
        }
        date = date.plusDays(1);
    }
    System.out.println(row);

}
```

Which prints....

```
Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat
                 1   2   3  
 4   5   6   7   8   9  10  
11  12  13  14  15  16  17  
18  19  20  21  22  23  24  
25  26  27  28  29  30  31
```

And because I was having so much fub, November...

```
Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat
 1   2   3   4   5   6   7  
 8   9  10  11  12  13  14  
15  16  17  18  19  20  21  
22  23  24  25  26  27  28  
29  30
```

Now, obviously, I've not implemented your "event" logic, but I left space in the format for it (I just left it blank in the example)

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void DisplayEvents(Events[] event, int firstWeekday) {
       int weekDayIndex =0;
       System.out.println("Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat");
        System.out.print("1");
        weekDayIndex++;
        for(int day = 2; day < event.length;day++){
            if(weekDayIndex== 7){
                weekDayIndex = 0;
                 System.out.println();
                System.out.print(day);
                weekDayIndex++;
            } else {
                System.out.print(String.format("%1$4s", day));
                weekDayIndex++;
            }
        }

    }
```

It prints:

> Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat
>
> 1  2   3   4   5   6   7
>
> 8   9  10  11  12  13  14
>
> 15  16  17  18  19  20  21
>
> 22  23  24  25  26  27  28 29